# Exclude upper parent when applying css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My problem is that I've got to apply some CSS styles to every image which parent is a link, except those links that are inside a `<li>` element. Here is my code:

```
$("img").parent("a").css({"padding": "0", "border": "0 none", "background-color": "transparent"})
```

It works fine with images posted in the main page, but it ruins my top menu too cause it has an image inside a link (for language selection).

Is there a way to apply the styles to every linked image, **except** those which parent is a `<li>` element? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...apply some CSS styles to every image

You can target anything but a `<li>`, then anchors, then images

```
$('*:not(li) > a img').css()
```

or filter

```
$('a img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('li').length === 0;
}).css();
```

As it looks like you're really applying those styles to the anchors, not the images

```
$('a:has(img)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('li').length === 0;
}).css();
```

Comment: Since $(this).closest('li').length returns false for 0 , guess you don't need $(this).closest('li').length === 0

Comment: @DinoMyte - not really, one could do `return ! $(this).closest('li').length` as well, but I like the `=== 0`, it makes it clearer that the intention is to not find anything, i.e. no LI parent up the DOM

Comment: wouldn't `$('*:not(li) a img')` match "body li a img" ? i think a `>` might help...

Comment: @dandavis - That's why I added the filter method, using the asterisk usually doesn't end up how you think it will, it's a crappy selector, and as you say, it will probably match `li a img`, but in some other way, like `body a img`, where `a` is also inside `li` etc. Using the direct child selector might be better, I'll add that, but it's not really clear wether or not the anchor is a direct child of the `li`, in which case that wouldn't work either.